# Type or namespace name 'OwinStartupAttribute' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

## Error

**The type or namespace name 'OwinStartupAttribute' could not be found

The type or namespace name 'OwinStartup' could not be found**

### Code

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Employee.Web.Models.Startup))]
namespace Employee.Web.Models.Startup
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Using:

- .net 4.0
- MVC 4
- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb (1.1.0.0)
- Microsoft.Owin (2.1.0.0)
- Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb (2.1.0.0)
- Owin (1.0.0.0)
- Visual Studio 2013

Installed singlar after Referencing Microsoft.Owin using the command  `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Version 1.1.3`

**UPDATE:**
I removed `[assembly:..`
and also added this in web.config:
`<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="Employee.Web.Models.Startup" />`

The error now says
**'Owin.IAppBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'MapSignalR' and no extension method 'MapSignalR' accepting a first argument of type 'Owin.IAppBuilder' could be found**

Comment: I tested signalr with Asp.net web application using .net4.5. All was fine. Now trying to integrate in .net4.0 mvc4 and these errors pop up

Answer (score 2):

To fix that:

1. Make sure that `Microsoft.Owin` is installed
2. Right-click on the
   project and click `add item` and search for *"startup"*
3. Now, you already have an OWIN `Startup.cs` class. click on `OWIN Startup
   class` and just add it under `Startup1.cs` then the error will be
   gone.
4. `Delete` the added `Startup1.cs`

finally, `rebuild`.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Create One Class With Name Startup this will help you..

```
public class Startup
{
   public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
   {
      app.MapSignalR();
   }
}
```

In addition to this, if your startup class is somehow not in your default name space, add a web config line to the  area like:
 `<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="[NameSpace].Startup" />`

[Here](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection) is more explenation.

Comment: What about the "In addition..." part?

Answer (score 1):

1. I removed Microsoft.Owin from my project's references
2. downloaded the .dll and placed it into the project's `bin/` folder
3. Right clicked references, add, browse, find the .dll, it builds!
4. Make sure the packages.config version of Owin matches your downloaded version.